# Redirecting Std::cout from p/invoked dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, named-pipes, io-redirection

## What I'm trying to do

I would like to redirect `std::cout` in a dll I `P/Invoke` from `C#`.  To do so, I redirect via `SetStdHandle` using named pipes wrapped in streams.

## Problem

For some strange reason, this only works once.  When calling `Do1()` the second time, the redirect does not appear to work at all.  Why is that?

#### Note:

I'm aware of lifetime issues in the background thread that drains the stream, which I will address but is not the root cause for this issue.

## Source.cpp

```
#pragma once

__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl main();

#include <iostream>

void main() {
    std::cout << "Test 1" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

## Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace RedirectDllOutput
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("..\\..\\..\\..\\x64\\Debug\\NativeDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private static extern void main();

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int SetStdHandle(int device, IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

        private static int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Do1();
            Do1();
        }

        private static void Do1()
        {
            int id = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
                .Id;
            using (var serverPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream("consoleRedirect" + id, PipeDirection.In, 1))
            using (var clientPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "consoleRedirect" + id, PipeDirection.Out, PipeOptions.WriteThrough))
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                    state =>
                    {
                        serverPipe.WaitForConnection();
                        using (var stm = new StreamReader(serverPipe))
                        {
                            while (serverPipe.IsConnected)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    var txt = stm.ReadLine();
                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                                    {
//                                        Console.WriteLine(txt);
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (IOException)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    null);
                clientPipe.Connect();
                var prevStdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
                var newStdHandle = new HandleRef(clientPipe, clientPipe.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle());
                var stdHandle = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, newStdHandle.Handle);
                main();
                var handle = SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, prevStdHandle);
                clientPipe.WaitForPipeDrain();
                clientPipe.Close();
                serverPipe.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is it just me, or does the title seem like it's for an entirely different question? What does this have to do with Excel or Clipboards?

Comment: hahahaha, fixed the title, my bad!